# new values on $(window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I first do this and it works:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 0;
    var myLeft = $("#container").offset().left;
    var myRight = myLeft + $("#container").outerWidth();
    var newWidth = $("#container").width();
    $("#head").animate({width: newWidth});
    $("#head").css("marginLeft", myLeft).css("marginRight", myRight);
    $('.box').each(function() {
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn();
       delay += 250;
    });
 });
```

Then i run this but it does't work, ideally it would have to work on each window resize:

```
 function doSomething() {
   var myLeft = $("#container").offset().left;
   var myRight = myLeft + $("#container").outerWidth();
   var newWidth = $("#container").width();
   $("#head").animate({width: newWidth});
   $("#head").css("marginLeft", myLeft).css("marginRight", myRight);
  };

 var resizeTimer;
 $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
 });
```

But it looks like as the new sizes are not applied each time there is a window resize, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window resize was happening before the new values were set therefore the trick was to include a timer delay for the window resize event:

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
  clearTimeout (timer);
   timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
```

});

```
$(window).resize(function() {
delay(function(){
    if ($("#head").width() != $("#container").width()){
        var myLeft = $("#container").offset().left;
        var newWidth = $("#container").innerWidth();
        var myRight = $(window).width() - ($("#container").offset().left + $("#container").outerWidth());
        $("#head").animate({ width: newWidth, marginLeft: myLeft, marginRight: myRight }, "fast");
    }
}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#head").css("margin-left", myLeft + "px").css("margin-right", myRight + "px");
```

You also seam to be using an unnecessary "each" clause as you're not doing anything for each box, only on `#head`. Are you sure you mean that?

Comment: it works when i first run it, but it doesn't on windows resize

Comment: Remove you `#head` statements from the each function in your `doSomething` function, you don't seem to need to perform those actions for every `.box`.

Comment: yep i have updated the question with the correct code, didn't even need those css in the each box when i first run it. Yet i can't have it working, works when it starts but never on resize